# why does it print 1234567.875000 and not 1234567.890000

Tags: c, input, output

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float y=1234567.89;
    printf("%f",y);
    return 0;
}
```

the output of the code is 1234567.875000

also I tried this
#include <stdio.h>

```
int main() {
    float y=123.89;
    printf("%f",y);

    return 0;
}
```

now the output is 123.889999

Comment: Because `float` doesn't have enough precision to distinguish those values. Use `double` instead.

Comment: `1234567.875` is the closest value to `1234567.89` an IEEE single-precision number can represent. An IEEE double-precision number would be more precise: `1234567.88999999989755451679229736328125`. However, as you can see, it's not exact either. This is because 89/100 is a periodic number in binary (`0.11(10001111010111000010)`), just like 1/3 is a periodic number in decimal. It would take infinite storage to store accurately as a floating point number.